# Regex: Matching arithmetic operators and two-character operators

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to match Matlab operators in a string. These operators may be `"+", "-", "*", "/", ".*", "./",` etc. (I enclose the operators in `"` to indicate that there are two-character operators in Matlab).

A character set works with no problems for the one-character operators. For example, this regex `[\+\-\*\/]` matches one-character operators just fine in the following test string:

```
myVar = 1.0 * 5 + 1 / 2 + a .* b + a ./ b;
```

The trouble comes when I try to include the two-character operators. The following expression `[\+\-\*\/\.\*]` also matches the `.` in `1.0`.

Being a newcomer to regexps, I tried including a group inside the character set like this `[\+\-\*\/(\.\*)]` but it does not work.

Any idea how can I include a two-character element in a character set?

Comment: Btw, only `/` and `]` needs to be escaped inside a character class, provided you put the dash as the last character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put that two char  pattern inside a group.

```
(\.[\/*]|[+*\/-])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hO0cX1/1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use alternation if you wish to match more than one character at a time:

```
(?:\.[*\/]|[+*\/-])
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jC9pF3/1)

*The `(?: ... )` syntax is to create a group without a memory capture.*